# Merge one repository into another whilst keeping commit history of both

Tags: git, github, repository

I am not even sure if this is possible, but I have two projects. The first `Main` is a few years old and the main project. We recently created a `Components` package for use in this but as a standalone repo.

The idea was the components were to be universal, but as this is no longer the case, we want to merge `Components` into `Main` and keep some semblance of commit history in the component files.

The `Main` repo shouldn't need any major changed by other users other than to do a `git pull` or similar once everything is sorted to get all the new `components` into `Main`

I would like the `Components` repo to be a subfolder somewhere in `Main`

How would I go about doing this?

Is there a solution for this?

Any help is greatly appreciated